# How do I clear div of other tabs when tab is selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click load more in tab1, images are showing up. When I select another tab it's not clearing images from the previous tab. Can someone help me how to solve it? I will be appreciated. Thanks.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        tabs();
        instafeed();
    });
    
    function tabs() {
        $(".tab-content").hide();
        $(".tab-content:first").show(); 
    
        $("div.tabs .button").click(function() {
            $("div.tabs .button").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".tab-content").hide();
            var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
            $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
        });
    }
    
    function instafeed() {    
        var myButton = $('#load-more');
      
        var tab1 = new Instafeed({
        target: 'tab1',
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'cofiwear',
        clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
        limit: '14',
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        link: 'true',
        template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
            after: function() {
                if (!this.hasNext()) {
                    myButton.hide();
                }
            },
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
            after : function() {  console.log('a'); }
        });
    
        // call feed.next() on button click
         $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
          
          tab1.next();
         });
    
         tab1.run();
        
        
         var tab2 = new Instafeed({
        target: 'tab2',
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'cofiwear',
        clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
        limit: '14',
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        link: 'true',
        template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
           after: function() {
                if (!this.hasNext()) {
                    myButton.hide();
                }
            },
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
            after : function() {  console.log('a'); }
        });
    
        // call feed.next() on button click
         $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
          
          tab2.next();
         });
    
         tab2.run();
      
         myButton.on('click', function() {
            // run feeds
            tab1.next();
            tab2.next();
        });
    
    }
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3
(function(){var e,t;e=function(){function e(e,t){var n,r;this.options={target:"instafeed",get:"popular",resolution:"thumbnail",sortBy:"most-recent",links:!0,mock:!1,useHttp:!1};if(typeof e=="object")for(n in e)r=e[n],this.options[n]=r;this.context=t!=null?t:this,this.unique=this._genKey()}return e.prototype.hasNext=function(){return typeof this.context.nextUrl=="string"&&this.context.nextUrl.length>0},e.prototype.next=function(){return this.hasNext()?this.run(this.context.nextUrl):!1},e.prototype.run=function(t){var n,r,i;if(typeof this.options.clientId!="string"&&typeof this.options.accessToken!="string")throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");if(typeof this.options.accessToken!="string"&&typeof this.options.clientId!="string")throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");return this.options.before!=null&&typeof this.options.before=="function"&&this.options.before.call(this),typeof document!="undefined"&&document!==null&&(i=document.createElement("script"),i.id="instafeed-fetcher",i.src=t||this._buildUrl(),n=document.getElementsByTagName("head"),n[0].appendChild(i),r="instafeedCache"+this.unique,window[r]=new e(this.options,this),window[r].unique=this.unique),!0},e.prototype.parse=function(e){var t,n,r,i,s,o,u,a,f,l,c,h,p,d,v,m,g,y,b,w,E,S;if(typeof e!="object"){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,"Invalid JSON data"),!1;throw new Error("Invalid JSON response")}if(e.meta.code!==200){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,e.meta.error_message),!1;throw new Error("Error from Instagram: "+e.meta.error_message)}if(e.data.length===0){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,"No images were returned from Instagram"),!1;throw new Error("No images were returned from Instagram")}this.options.success!=null&&typeof this.options.success=="function"&&this.options.success.call(this,e),this.context.nextUrl="",e.pagination!=null&&(this.context.nextUrl=e.pagination.next_url);if(this.options.sortBy!=="most-recent"){this.options.sortBy==="random"?d=["","random"]:d=this.options.sortBy.split("-"),p=d[0]==="least"?!0:!1;switch(d[1]){case"random":e.data.sort(function(){return.5-Math.random()});break;case"recent":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"created_time",p);break;case"liked":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"likes.count",p);break;case"commented":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"comments.count",p);break;default:throw new Error("Invalid option for sortBy: '"+this.options.sortBy+"'.")}}if(typeof document!="undefined"&&document!==null&&this.options.mock===!1){a=e.data,this.options.limit!=null&&a.length>this.options.limit&&(a=a.slice(0,this.options.limit+1||9e9)),n=document.createDocumentFragment(),this.options.filter!=null&&typeof this.options.filter=="function"&&(a=this._filter(a,this.options.filter));if(this.options.template!=null&&typeof this.options.template=="string"){i="",o="",l="",v=document.createElement("div");for(m=0,b=a.length;m<b;m++)s=a[m],u=s.images[this.options.resolution].url,this.options.useHttp||(u=u.replace("http://","//")),o=this._makeTemplate(this.options.template,{model:s,id:s.id,link:s.link,image:u,caption:this._getObjectProperty(s,"caption.text"),likes:s.likes.count,comments:s.comments.count,location:this._getObjectProperty(s,"location.name")}),i+=o;v.innerHTML=i,S=[].slice.call(v.childNodes);for(g=0,w=S.length;g<w;g++)h=S[g],n.appendChild(h)}else for(y=0,E=a.length;y<E;y++)s=a[y],f=document.createElement("img"),f.src=s.images[this.options.resolution].url,this.options.links===!0?(t=document.createElement("a"),t.href=s.link,t.appendChild(f),n.appendChild(t)):n.appendChild(f);document.getElementById(this.options.target).appendChild(n),r=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],r.removeChild(document.getElementById("instafeed-fetcher")),c="instafeedCache"+this.unique,window[c]=void 0;try{delete window[c]}catch(x){}}return this.options.after!=null&&typeof this.options.after=="function"&&this.options.after.call(this),!0},e.prototype._buildUrl=function(){var e,t,n;e="https://api.instagram.com/v1";switch(this.options.get){case"popular":t="media/popular";break;case"tagged":if(typeof this.options.tagName!="string")throw new Error("No tag name specified. Use the 'tagName' option.");t="tags/"+this.options.tagName+"/media/recent";break;case"location":if(typeof this.options.locationId!="number")throw new Error("No location specified. Use the 'locationId' option.");t="locations/"+this.options.locationId+"/media/recent";break;case"user":if(typeof this.options.userId!="number")throw new Error("No user specified. Use the 'userId' option.");if(typeof this.options.accessToken!="string")throw new Error("No access token. Use the 'accessToken' option.");t="users/"+this.options.userId+"/media/recent";break;default:throw new Error("Invalid option for get: '"+this.options.get+"'.")}return n=""+e+"/"+t,this.options.accessToken!=null?n+="?access_token="+this.options.accessToken:n+="?client_id="+this.options.clientId,this.options.limit!=null&&(n+="&count="+this.options.limit),n+="&callback=instafeedCache"+this.unique+".parse",n},e.prototype._genKey=function(){var e;return e=function(){return((1+Math.random())*65536|0).toString(16).substring(1)},""+e()+e()+e()+e()},e.prototype._makeTemplate=function(e,t){var n,r,i,s,o;r=/(?:\{{2})([\w\[\]\.]+)(?:\}{2})/,n=e;while(r.test(n))i=n.match(r)[1],s=(o=this._getObjectProperty(t,i))!=null?o:"",n=n.replace(r,""+s);return n},e.prototype._getObjectProperty=function(e,t){var n,r;t=t.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g,".$1"),r=t.split(".");while(r.length){n=r.shift();if(!(e!=null&&n in e))return null;e=e[n]}return e},e.prototype._sortBy=function(e,t,n){var r;return r=function(e,r){var i,s;return i=this._getObjectProperty(e,t),s=this._getObjectProperty(r,t),n?i>s?1:-1:i<s?1:-1},e.sort(r.bind(this)),e},e.prototype._filter=function(e,t){var n,r,i,s,o;n=[],i=function(e){if(t(e))return n.push(e)};for(s=0,o=e.length;s<o;s++)r=e[s],i(r);return n},e}(),t=typeof exports!="undefined"&&exports!==null?exports:window,t.Instafeed=e}).call(this);
</script>


<section class="container-wrap" id="community">
 <div class="tabs">
  <button class="button active" rel="tab1">#tab1</button>
  <button class="button" rel="tab2">#tab2</button>
 </div>

 <div id="tab-container">
        <div class="tab-content instafeed" id="tab1"></div>
        <div class="tab-content instafeed" id="tab2"></div>
    </div>
  <button class="btn-wrap" id="load-more" href="#">
         <div class="btn">load more</div>
     </button>
</section>
```

my code is here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unuLyzx0/170/)

Comment: It's not very clear what is supposed to happen, but you can use `$(tabId).empty();` to empty contents of the `div`.

Comment: Check out this example
https://www.facebook.com/braveandco/app/267091300008193/?ref=page_internal

When you are in tab1 and click "more" images is showing, and when u click another tab. It's clear the previous tab content. @VictorLevin

Answer (score 1):

This can be improved a lot more!
Anyway it's fixed now, just test it with a different clientId.

```
$(function(){
  var myButton = $('#load-more');
  var tab1 = new Instafeed({
      target: 'tab1',
      get: 'tagged',
      tagName: 'cofiwear',
      clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
      limit: '14',
      sortBy: 'most-recent',
      link: 'true',
      template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
          after: function() {
              if (!this.hasNext()) {
                  myButton.hide();
              }
          },
      resolution: 'standard_resolution',
          after : function() {  console.log('a'); }
  });
  var tab2 = new Instafeed({
      target: 'tab2',
      get: 'tagged',
      tagName: 'cofiwear',
      clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
      limit: '14',
      sortBy: 'most-recent',
      link: 'true',
      template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
          after: function() {
              if (!this.hasNext()) {
                  myButton.hide();
              }
          },
      resolution: 'standard_resolution',
          after : function() {  console.log('a'); }
  });
  tab1.run();
  //tab2.run();
  myButton.on('click',function(){
      var activeTab = $("div.tabs .button.active").attr("rel");
      if (activeTab=='tab1') {
            tab1.next()
      }else{
            tab2.next()
      }
  });
  $('.button[rel="tab2"').one('click',function(){
    tab2.run()
  });
  $(".tab-content:not(:first)").hide();
  $("div.tabs .button").on('click',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
      $("div.tabs .button").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(".tab-content").hide();
      $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4sggnf60

If you need to put more tags, just read this post on github: [..feed display 
more then one tag..](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/12)

Comment: Thanks. Can you show it to me how it looks like in jsfiddle? Appreciated. I try to put the code u gave me but its not working. I think I did wrong. @Vixed

Comment: Thanks . How? @Victor Levin

Comment: Can you update the jsfiddle code, so I can see the difference ? :)

Comment: I've edited my answer adding the @VictorLevin suggestion. Take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unuLyzx0/171/)

Comment: sorry! forked [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d369kph9/) but I can't edit the comment I sent before. thanks @Anthony

Comment: Is not working. When I'm in tab1 and click load more, and when I click to tab2, tab content is empty. I want the tab2 to show images. Tab2 should show content.

Comment: When you check out my example, you know what i'm talking about.
https://www.facebook.com/braveandco/app/267091300008193/?ref=page_internal
 After I click load more btn in tab1, tab2 should tab content wihthout load more images. Sorry Im not good in explaning :( @Vixed

Comment: Don't worry, I'm looking for a solution ;)

Comment: Thanks...thanks for the help...looking forward for the answer @Vixed

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reorganize your code hoping this will help you. Now when you click a button the content of the other button is hidden but this does not solve. The problem is when you ask for loading the problem is understanding the active tab and so fullfil only that tab:

```js
$(function() {
  tabs();
  instafeed();
});
function tabs() {
  $(".tab-content").hide();
  var tabAcive = $(".button.active").attr('rel');
  $("#" + tabAcive).show();

  $("div.tabs .button").click(function() {
    $("div.tabs .button").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tab-content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();
  });
}

var instafeedArrObj={};
function instafeed() {
  var myButton = $('#load-more');

  $('.tab-content.instafeed').each(function(index, element ) {
    var tabObj = new Instafeed({
      target: element.id,
      get: 'tagged',
      tagName: 'cofiwear',
      clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
      limit: '14',
      sortBy: 'most-recent',
      link: 'true',
      template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
      after: function () {
        if (!this.hasNext()) {
          myButton.hide();
        }
      },
      resolution: 'standard_resolution',
      after: function () {
        //console.log('a');
      }
    });
    instafeedArrObj[element.id] = tabObj;
    tabObj.run();
    $(':button[rel="' + element.id + '"]').click({tabObj: tabObj}, function (e) {
      //$(':button[rel][rel!="tab3"]').hide();
      $('#' + element.id).empty();
      e.data.tabObj.next();
      //tab1.next();
    });
  });

  myButton.on('click', function () {
    var tabAcive = $(".button.active").attr('rel');
    $("#" + tabAcive).show();
    instafeedArrObj[tabAcive].next()
  });
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://instafeedjs.com/js/instafeed.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3
        (function(){var e,t;e=function(){function e(e,t){var n,r;this.options={target:"instafeed",get:"popular",resolution:"thumbnail",sortBy:"most-recent",links:!0,mock:!1,useHttp:!1};if(typeof e=="object")for(n in e)r=e[n],this.options[n]=r;this.context=t!=null?t:this,this.unique=this._genKey()}return e.prototype.hasNext=function(){return typeof this.context.nextUrl=="string"&&this.context.nextUrl.length>0},e.prototype.next=function(){return this.hasNext()?this.run(this.context.nextUrl):!1},e.prototype.run=function(t){var n,r,i;if(typeof this.options.clientId!="string"&&typeof this.options.accessToken!="string")throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");if(typeof this.options.accessToken!="string"&&typeof this.options.clientId!="string")throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");return this.options.before!=null&&typeof this.options.before=="function"&&this.options.before.call(this),typeof document!="undefined"&&document!==null&&(i=document.createElement("script"),i.id="instafeed-fetcher",i.src=t||this._buildUrl(),n=document.getElementsByTagName("head"),n[0].appendChild(i),r="instafeedCache"+this.unique,window[r]=new e(this.options,this),window[r].unique=this.unique),!0},e.prototype.parse=function(e){var t,n,r,i,s,o,u,a,f,l,c,h,p,d,v,m,g,y,b,w,E,S;if(typeof e!="object"){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,"Invalid JSON data"),!1;throw new Error("Invalid JSON response")}if(e.meta.code!==200){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,e.meta.error_message),!1;throw new Error("Error from Instagram: "+e.meta.error_message)}if(e.data.length===0){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,"No images were returned from Instagram"),!1;throw new Error("No images were returned from Instagram")}this.options.success!=null&&typeof this.options.success=="function"&&this.options.success.call(this,e),this.context.nextUrl="",e.pagination!=null&&(this.context.nextUrl=e.pagination.next_url);if(this.options.sortBy!=="most-recent"){this.options.sortBy==="random"?d=["","random"]:d=this.options.sortBy.split("-"),p=d[0]==="least"?!0:!1;switch(d[1]){case"random":e.data.sort(function(){return.5-Math.random()});break;case"recent":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"created_time",p);break;case"liked":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"likes.count",p);break;case"commented":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"comments.count",p);break;default:throw new Error("Invalid option for sortBy: '"+this.options.sortBy+"'.")}}if(typeof document!="undefined"&&document!==null&&this.options.mock===!1){a=e.data,this.options.limit!=null&&a.length>this.options.limit&&(a=a.slice(0,this.options.limit+1||9e9)),n=document.createDocumentFragment(),this.options.filter!=null&&typeof this.options.filter=="function"&&(a=this._filter(a,this.options.filter));if(this.options.template!=null&&typeof this.options.template=="string"){i="",o="",l="",v=document.createElement("div");for(m=0,b=a.length;m<b;m++)s=a[m],u=s.images[this.options.resolution].url,this.options.useHttp||(u=u.replace("http://","//")),o=this._makeTemplate(this.options.template,{model:s,id:s.id,link:s.link,image:u,caption:this._getObjectProperty(s,"caption.text"),likes:s.likes.count,comments:s.comments.count,location:this._getObjectProperty(s,"location.name")}),i+=o;v.innerHTML=i,S=[].slice.call(v.childNodes);for(g=0,w=S.length;g<w;g++)h=S[g],n.appendChild(h)}else for(y=0,E=a.length;y<E;y++)s=a[y],f=document.createElement("img"),f.src=s.images[this.options.resolution].url,this.options.links===!0?(t=document.createElement("a"),t.href=s.link,t.appendChild(f),n.appendChild(t)):n.appendChild(f);document.getElementById(this.options.target).appendChild(n),r=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],r.removeChild(document.getElementById("instafeed-fetcher")),c="instafeedCache"+this.unique,window[c]=void 0;try{delete window[c]}catch(x){}}return this.options.after!=null&&typeof this.options.after=="function"&&this.options.after.call(this),!0},e.prototype._buildUrl=function(){var e,t,n;e="https://api.instagram.com/v1";switch(this.options.get){case"popular":t="media/popular";break;case"tagged":if(typeof this.options.tagName!="string")throw new Error("No tag name specified. Use the 'tagName' option.");t="tags/"+this.options.tagName+"/media/recent";break;case"location":if(typeof this.options.locationId!="number")throw new Error("No location specified. Use the 'locationId' option.");t="locations/"+this.options.locationId+"/media/recent";break;case"user":if(typeof this.options.userId!="number")throw new Error("No user specified. Use the 'userId' option.");if(typeof this.options.accessToken!="string")throw new Error("No access token. Use the 'accessToken' option.");t="users/"+this.options.userId+"/media/recent";break;default:throw new Error("Invalid option for get: '"+this.options.get+"'.")}return n=""+e+"/"+t,this.options.accessToken!=null?n+="?access_token="+this.options.accessToken:n+="?client_id="+this.options.clientId,this.options.limit!=null&&(n+="&count="+this.options.limit),n+="&callback=instafeedCache"+this.unique+".parse",n},e.prototype._genKey=function(){var e;return e=function(){return((1+Math.random())*65536|0).toString(16).substring(1)},""+e()+e()+e()+e()},e.prototype._makeTemplate=function(e,t){var n,r,i,s,o;r=/(?:\{{2})([\w\[\]\.]+)(?:\}{2})/,n=e;while(r.test(n))i=n.match(r)[1],s=(o=this._getObjectProperty(t,i))!=null?o:"",n=n.replace(r,""+s);return n},e.prototype._getObjectProperty=function(e,t){var n,r;t=t.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g,".$1"),r=t.split(".");while(r.length){n=r.shift();if(!(e!=null&&n in e))return null;e=e[n]}return e},e.prototype._sortBy=function(e,t,n){var r;return r=function(e,r){var i,s;return i=this._getObjectProperty(e,t),s=this._getObjectProperty(r,t),n?i>s?1:-1:i<s?1:-1},e.sort(r.bind(this)),e},e.prototype._filter=function(e,t){var n,r,i,s,o;n=[],i=function(e){if(t(e))return n.push(e)};for(s=0,o=e.length;s<o;s++)r=e[s],i(r);return n},e}(),t=typeof exports!="undefined"&&exports!==null?exports:window,t.Instafeed=e}).call(this);
    </script>
<section class="container-wrap" id="community">
    <div class="tabs">
        <button class="button active" rel="tab1">#tab1</button>
        <button class="button" rel="tab2">#tab2</button>
        <button class="button" rel="tab3">#tab3</button>
        <button class="button" rel="tab4">#tab4</button>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-container">
        <div class="tab-content instafeed" id="tab1"></div>
        <div class="tab-content instafeed" id="tab2"></div>
        <div class="tab-content instafeed" id="tab3"></div>
        <div class="tab-content instafeed" id="tab4"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-wrap" id="load-more" href="#">
        <div class="btn">load more</div>
    </button>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want everytime I click on tab1 or tab2, it shows the default which is 14 images . Since limit : 14 images. But when I click load more to load more images and click back to another tab, it should show 14 images back which is default. Sorry not good at explaining :( Please help. @gaemaf

Comment: @waisieli Try now and let me know

Comment: Thanks. That's what i want :) But If I will have 4 tabs or more, I have to do in this way? hide it and empty it for the tabs? I have to it individually if I have another tab. tab.hide() and tab.empty() .  Because I will have 4 tabs (multiple tabs) . Is there another way to do it to get the same result? Appreciated. @gaemaf

Comment: @waisieli Yes there are a lot of different ways to reduce the numbers of line code. Immagine for instance to consider only the final number in your case: 1, 2, 3,4. But this part is just for you, I am sure you want to exercise with jQuery.... bye

Comment: Can you show me other way to do it? a cleaner way. If I have 4 tabs, It's gonna be a lot of code. @gaemaf

Comment: @waisieli take a look. Of course it is always improvable. I hope now it is alll ok!!!

Comment: Thank you. That's what I want. For the tagName, i will have different tagName. Do I put in comma like this ...for example tagName: 'cofiwear', 'kitchen', 'candy', 'tee',  Is that correct if i want include other tagName? Do I have to put 4 clientId? @ gaemaf

Comment: Or do I have to do the tagName in an array? i'm sure if that's right. Do u know what I mean? var myTags = getMultipleTags(['glass', 'wood', 'rock']); But I don't how it works @gaemaf

Comment: I'm trying to do that but it doesn't work. Can you also show me with different tagName? Appreciated. @gaemaf

Comment: I can't solve the problem :( can you help me ? @gaemaf

Comment: hi gaemaf, I try to add different tagname but it doesn't work. do you know how to do that? can u help me with that? i need help. @gaemaf

Comment: @waisieli have you tried to copy my snippet? All the code you need is there.

Comment: Yes i did. The code works great, but my problem now is I don't know how to add different tagName. the tagName, i will have different tagName. Do I put in comma like this ...for example tagName: 'cofiwear', 'kitchen', 'candy', 'tee', Is that correct if i want include other tagName? Do I have to put 4 clientId? Because right now, all 4tabs is using the tagname 'cofiwear', but i will have different tagname for other tab. Do you know how to do that? @ gaemaf

Comment: @waisieli you could replicate the behoviour for all the four tagname, using the first with the code you already have, after you can duplicate that code and use the second tagname, and so on. This could be one solution.

Comment: I'm not sure which part I should replicate. I try it and It doesn't work. can you show it to me? please @gaemaf

Comment: Do I replicate the whole js or the var tabObj = new Instafeed({}) ? If I replicate it 4 times , I should have 4 tabObj? I'm not sure if i didn't it right. i need help :(  @gaemaf

Comment: I really need your help. can you show it to me for the last time? I try what u said but its not working. :( @gaemaf